# Displaying unusual characters in HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, character-encoding, jinja2

I pulled the following string from my database:

"Wright is suddenly thrust into a far-from-mundane existence that he takes to surprisingly well … once he gets acclimated to it."

This is exactly the text as printed out on the console. Notice the triple dot is a single character.

Now when I pass this data into HTML through template I get the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 383: ordinal not in range(128)`

Any idea how to fix this? Do I need to encode to UTF-8 somehow. I am using python for my backend.

**EDIT**

The backend code is:

```
print "INFO: ", data[2]

return render_template('index.html', title=data[1], info=data[2].encode("utf-8"), backdrop=data[4], imdbrat=data[7], rtrat=data[9], cert=data[10], yt=data[11], runtime=data[12]);
```

And in the template (index.html) I have:

```
<p> {{info}} </p>
```

The output is:

```
INFO:  The life of Danny Wright, a salesman forever on the road, veers into dangerous and surreal territory when he wanders into a Mexican bar and meets a mysterious stranger, Julian, who's very likely a hit man. Their meeting sets off a chain of events that will change their lives forever, as Wright is suddenly thrust into a far-from-mundane existence that he takes to surprisingly well … once he gets acclimated to it.
[2016-12-17 21:06:14,846] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/dennis/moviechoosy/moviechoosy/app.py", line 31, in home
    return render_template('index.html', title=data[1], info=data[2].encode("utf-8"), backdrop=data[4], imdbrat=data[7], rtrat=data[9], cert=data[10], yt=data[11], runtime=data[12]);
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 383: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: "string with weird characters".encode('utf-8') ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Are you still getting the error ? Could you post your code ? I had a similar issue, my answer solved it but you probably have to convert it at some other place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '...' character is a horizontal ellipsis.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> c = unicodedata.lookup('HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS')
>>> c
u'\u2026'
>>> print c
…
```

Encoded as utf-8, it begins with 0xe2:

```
>>> b = c.encode('utf-8')
>>> b
'\xe2\x80\xa6'
```

The [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/unicode/#the-golden-rule) say that non-ascii strings for templates should be decoded to unicode when being passed to `render_template`.

> if you need anything else than ASCII in a string you have to mark this
>   string as Unicode string by prefixing it with a lowercase u. (like
>   u'Hänsel und Gretel')

So it seems you have a Python2 string from your database which is encoded as utf-8.  So you need to *decode* to unicode

```
>>> u = b.decode('utf-8')
```

and then Flask/Jinja2 should handle it correctly.